# run Excel VBA script on multiple workbooks-nothing is happening with current code

Tags: vba, excel, batch-file

I have an excel VBA script that I want to run across many Excel Workbooks.  They are all stored in one folder.  I thought that the code below would work, but nothing happens.  I don't even get any kind of error. (PSAT is the name of my VBA script that I want to run on all of the workbooks).

```
Sub Batch()    
MyPath = "T:\Program Evaluation\Sam\AP Potential\School Reports\Reports"    
MyTemplate = "*.xls*"    
MyName = Dir(MyPath & MyTemplate)   
Do While MyName <> ""    
    Workbooks.Open MyPath & MyName    
    PSAT    
    Workbooks(MyName).Close (True)    
    MyName = Dir   
Loop    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the ending backslash on your folder path.

```
Sub Batch()    
Dim wb as Workbook, MyPath, MyTemplate, MyName

MyPath = "T:\Program Evaluation\Sam\AP Potential\School Reports\Reports\"   
MyTemplate = "*.xls*"    
MyName = Dir(MyPath & MyTemplate)   
Do While MyName <> ""    
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyName)    
    PSAT    
    wb.Close True    
    MyName = Dir()   
Loop    
End Sub
```

Comment: ok-that helped..but now it's just opening the first workbook and running the macro.  it is not saving or moving to the next one.

Comment: So `wb.Close` doesn't do anything?  Or do you mean it's just opening the same one over and over?

Comment: it seems to just open the 1st one and get stuck.  it doesnt save it either.  maybe i should save and close the workbook within the PSAT macro?

Comment: ok- it sort of works until i save the macro.  If I just paste your code in and run it- it will run, but after each run it asks me to save the macro--so if my folder contains 5 spreadsheets, a pop up comes up 5 times asking if I want to save the psatmacro workbook (which I've saved as an excel macro enabled template because I read somewhere to do that...not sure if that matters) but between closing the pop up window about saving the macro- the code runs and works.  However, if I save the macro, close out and go back in and try to run it- it gets stuck on the first workbook in the folder.

Comment: The PSAT macro runs fine.

Comment: Is the macro in the same folder as the files you're trying to process? If Yes then you should check the filename in the loop and skip that one...

Comment: nope- it's in a different folder:
Macro is here: T:\Program Evaluation\Sam\AP Potential\School Reports
files are here: T:\Program Evaluation\Sam\AP Potential\School Reports\Reports